# Select everything before a colon en put it between quotes

Tags: regex, atom-editor

I have a big array and I need to get everything before the colon between quotes

I've tried this regex but it didn't work for me.

```
^([/.+?(?=:)]+)$
```

this is my array now:

```
A0 05 15 : "rgb(60, 50, 51)",
A0 05 25 : "rgb(82, 69, 71)",
S 2030-B : "rgb(120, 172, 191)",
S 2030-B10 : "rgb(119, 175, 187)"
```

What I want it do be:

```
"A0 05 15" : "rgb(60, 50, 51)",
"A0 05 25" : "rgb(82, 69, 71)",
"S 2030-B" : "rgb(120, 172, 191)",
"S 2030-B10" : "rgb(119, 175, 187)"
```

Comment: Find `\h*(.+?)\h*:` replace `$1 :` https://regex101.com/r/QXmMhX/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, we might want to have two capturing groups, one for keys and one for values, similar to:

```
(.+)(?:\s+):(?:\s+)(".+",?)
```

then make a replacement with:

```
"$1":$2
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/HBFEkL/1)

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]